# Programmatically multi language content in Alfresco

Tags: java, repository, alfresco

The requirement I receive is to model some existing content available on a SQL Server database using Alfresco content managment so, I create my new content model and it seems to working fine. But I've a problem with multi language: I know in Alfresco is possible for one node add multiple language (how can I do that using Java for a massive load?) but, I used also some aspects that need to be translated.

What do you usually do in that case? I thoug to follow this steps:

- Create Eng content and add aspects
- Create new child translted and add aspects

Is it correct? How can I make a node Multilingual programmatically (Java) and how can I add the new translate content with aspects? I took a look to Alfresco documentation but, I didn't find it, could you help me to find some documentation or tutorial about that?

UPDATE:

I'm trying to make a content multilangue:

```
void makeTranslation(Reference contentNodeRef, Locale locale) throws AlfrescoRuntimeException, Exception
    {
        try {
            NodeRef nodeRef = new NodeRef("workspace://SpacesStore/" + contentNodeRef.getUuid());           
            MultilingualContentServiceImpl multilingualContentServiceImpl = new MultilingualContentServiceImpl();       

            multilingualContentServiceImpl.makeTranslation(nodeRef, locale);
        }
        catch (org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException ex) {
            throw new AlfrescoRuntimeException(ex.getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new Exception(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

but, makeTranslation raise an nullPoint exception because MultilingualContentServiceImpl it's not initialized correctly. Any suggestion how to initialize it? I've to use spring but, how?

Any suggerstion or reply will be very helpful!

Thanks,
Andrea

Answer (score 2):

You can use MultilingualContentService to add translations. But! I guess your properties should be of type d:mltext (like cm:title and cm:description are) to support multilingual content.

This means if you access alfresco using browser with english language you will see a different description as someone using german language settings in browser. This can be a little confusing because in Share there is (was?) no identifier that the property is multilingual.

If you want your translations to appear everywhere, no matter what kind of language in browser people are using, then the better approach is to define some aspect (for example ex:translatable) with as many properties as you need translations. Then you can programatically (using Java or JavaScript) use search service to find nodes you want and add the aspect to them. Finally you then add properties (translations) of that aspect to the node.

I hope this helps to clear things a bit... :)

Comment: Suppose I have a new customized type, to support Multilangual, have I to set parent type to cm:mlContainer, right?

Comment: Explain first what you are trying to do. True multilingual (english users see english, german see german. Or type which can hold both translations and both translations are visible at the same time?

Comment: English consumer will see english, German consumer will see german using web site generate with web quick start. Author has to see all content. If the step is correct, I create a content with english, add Multilingual aspect, create a new content with translation and associate using mlChild association type

Comment: Hm.. Sounds about right. Haven't actually done this  before... :)